# Dual boot and USB Failure

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, kali-linux

I am currently trying to install two operating systems on my PC.

So far I have Windows 10 installed on one hard drive with a secondary hard drive for data storage. On my third hard drive, which is an SSD, I am trying to install a Linux OS. However, there is a problem. When the Linux starts to install, all my USB ports stop working so I am unable to use my mouse and keyboard. I thought this may be due to a disc not done properly or a problem with a specific OS so I tried a few things. I tried three different Linux OSes. On disc, I tried Ubuntu and Kali. The problem occurred when I clicked install or "try before installing". And on bootable USB I tried Linux Mint, however, I was unable to get that to work.

My PC specs:

CPU - AMD Piledriver FX-8 Eight Core 8350 Black Edition 4.00GHz (Socket AM3+) Processor

MotherBoard - Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3 AMD 990FX (Socket AM3+) DDR3 Motherboard

GPU - Gigabyte GeForce GTX 770 WindForce 3x OC 4096MB GDDR5 PCI-Express Graphics Card GV-N770OC-4GD)

RAM - TeamGroup Elite Black 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3 PC3-12800C11 1600MHz Dual Channel Kit (TED316GM1600HC11DC01)

Hard Drive 1 - Western Digital Caviar Green 1TB Internal Hard Drive, 3.5" HDD, SATA III - 6Gb/s, IntelliPower, 64MB Cache, 8ms, OEM

Hard Drive 2 - Western Digital Caviar Green 3TB Internal Hard Drive, 3.5" HDD, SATA III - 6Gb/s, IntelliPower, 64MB Cache, 8ms, OEM

Hard Drive 3 - SanDisk SSD 64 GB SATA III 2.5-inch Internal SSD (This is the one I want to put Linux on)

Thanks for any help,
Dan

**Edit**

Just a note - The most recent OS I am working on trying to install is Linux Kali. This is burned on a DVD and the USB ports work until [this point](http://docs.kali.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/01-install-select.png)

I am not using a laptop so both the mouse and keyboard stop working.

**Edit 2**
I took a picture and a get a long list of

```
[    x.xxxxxx] usb x-x: device descriptor read/64, error -71
```

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that you used the USB version of the ISO?

Comment: @Steampunkery I'm pretty sure I did. I think the problem was I didn't make a bootable USB properly. Anyway, that is not the main problem. I would like to find out why all the USBs stop working past clicking the first option - when the DVD launches a program

Comment: They probably stop working because the driver hasn't installed yet. Can't you navigate the install program with the keyboard?

Comment: @Steampunkery No both the mouse and keyboard stop working no matter what USB port they are in. Normally I would assume it was a hardware problem but all te ports seem to work in the bios and in windows

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I was thinking about a laptop with a built in keyboard. How are you putting the ISO on the USB? I use dd.

Comment: @Steampunkery at the moment I have it burnt on a disc. The current OS I am trying is Linux Kali, even though I have the exact same problem on Mint and Ubuntu, it will get as far as [this](http://docs.kali.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/01-install-select.png) in Linux Kali, and similar positions in Mint and Ubuntu. After this screen the USBs stop working

Comment: Try with the different combinations of IOMMU (AMD-Vi) and USB 3.0 option settings in the UEFI (i.e. on/on, on/off, off/on, off/off).

Comment: @Steampunkery If it helps see edit

Comment: @TomYan If it helps see the edit and I am not quite sure how to do what you are saying to try

Comment: Read 2-1 and 2-6 of the [manual](http://download.gigabyte.asia/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-990fxa-ud3_v.4.0_e.pdf). Press DEL to get into UEFI settings and you can found the options `R_USB3.0 Controller` and `IOMMU controller` under `Peripherals`.

Comment: @TomYan You sir are a legend. If you would like post an answer. I will mark it correct and the question will be answered so no passerbys will think it is un solved

Comment: @Dan I can't write a proper answer unless you can tell me which combination works for you. Also, there are four possible combinations, so is there only one that works? Or are there two or three?

Comment: @TomYan Ah yes sorry. Turning the` IOMMU controller` on and `R_USB3.0 Controller` off fixed the problems. None of the other combos worked

Comment: I wonder if those settings mean that you'll still be able to use USB 3 speeds / devices or may be limited to USB 2... Maybe a boot option may have worked too, iso's like Ubuntu's or Mint list some, like "noapic noacpi  irqpoll", there are lots more

Comment: @Xen2050 the USB 3.0 ports are handled by the VIA VL805 controller. If the option is turned off, I suppose none of the USB 3.0 ports would work at all (the two blue ports on the back banel and two possible front panel ports provided by the USB 3.0 headers)

Comment: @Dan If you need `R_USB3.0 Controller` to be on for your USB 3.0 devices or so, you can try to boot with the kernel parameter `iommu=soft` (test with `IOMMU Controller` on and off respectively).

Answer (score 1):

OK! As per the comments above, you burn the ISO onto the USB. I have had trouble with that in the past and I find that using dd is easier and more reliable. Look at this wiki post to see how to do it properly:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media

I know it's for arch Linux, but it definitely works. I have personally installed 10+ ISOs with this method. If you are making the USB on a windows computer, I find that it is easier to ask a friend to their Mac or go to a library if they have Macs there. If you know anybody who also uses linux then you can ask them instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate but I have burnt it on a DVD and it is not working. I am not sure if Linux Kali has a USB burnable version

Comment: Never mind I found a USB boot version for it and instruction on how to do it. I will get back to you once I have tried it on a USB boot

Comment: have you tried UNetBootIn?

Comment: No. I shall have a look and give it a try

Comment: Okay so a made a usb which was bootable and the same errors occur

Comment: how did you make it bootable, burn or dd or UNetBootIn?

Comment: I used `Win32 Disk Imager`. After changing the settings that Tom Yan suggested the USBs worked again and I was able to install the OS. Thank you for your help in the problem though

Answer (score 1):

I tried a web search for linux your motherboard name [*linux MotherBoard - Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3*](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=linux+MotherBoard+-+Gigabyte+990FXA-UD3) and the first link was here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143433

> Originally Posted by quattro_cs [View Post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12668021#post12668021)
>
> *In the BIOS, set IOMMU to "Enabled". That fixed both USB and networking for me.*

And further down, it suggests adding the boot option `iommu=soft` if further problems persist.